# Get Latest Js and Css files after new deployment

Tags: jquery, css, iis, model-view-controller, bundling-and-minification

Please guide me the way, how to get latest files after new deployment.
I have used mvc bundling for Js and Css files.

Every time I change the version in the url like this

"site.com/generalScript?version=7"

and reset IIS after deployment, but still need to complete refresh(ctrl+F5) my browser to get new changes.

Comment: is there nobody to answer?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Bundling will handle versioning for you so there is no need to manually set the version number. But if you are changing the number manually, that should force a new download if the version number changed since last time.